# multiple bitwise conditional

Tags: php

How can I perform a multiple OR statement in php?

I thought this would work, but doesn't.

```
if (($title != "section-1") | ($title != "section-2") | ($title != "section-3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (($title != "section-1") || ($title != "section-2") || ($title != "section-3")
```

Answer (score 3):

alternative approach

```
if(!in_array($title,array('section-1','section-2','section-3'))
```